# uhub Direct Connect server Configuration

Tags: dc++

I have installed and configured uhub Direct Connect server.

When I run the program, it echos"uhub started and listening on 1511....."

But when I use DC++ client to connect to the above hub, the client throws Invalid CID error and when i check the uhub log, its written"USER: login error. msg_inf_cid_invalid".

Below is the users.conf file

```
# uHub access control lists.
#
# Syntax: <command> [data]
#
# commands:
# 'user_reg'   - registered user with no particular privileges (data=nick:password)
# 'user_op'    - operator, can kick or ban people (data=nick:password)
# 'user_admin' - administrator, can do everything operators can, and reconfigure the hub (data=nick:password)
# 'deny_nick'  - nick name that is not accepted (example; Administrator)
# 'deny_ip'    - Unacceptable IP (masks can be specified as CIDR: 0.0.0.0/32 will block all IPv4)
# 'ban_nick'   - banned user by nick
# 'ban_cid'    - banned user by cid

# Administrator
# user_admin    userA:password1
# user_op       userB:password2

# We don't want users with these names
deny_nick Hub-Security
deny_nick Administrator
deny_nick root
deny_nick admin
deny_nick username
deny_nick user
deny_nick guest
deny_nick operator

# Banned users
# ban_nick H4X0R
# ban_cid FOIL5EK2UDZYAXT7UIUFEKL4SEBEAJE3INJDKAY

# ban by ip
#
# to ban by CIDR
# deny_ip 10.21.44.0/24
#
# to ban by IP-range.
# deny_ip 10.21.44.7-10.21.44.9
#
# to ban a single IP address
# deny_ip 10.21.44.7
# (which is equivalent to using):
# deny_ip 10.21.44.7/32

# Will not work, yet
# nat_ip 10.0.0.0/8
# nat_ip 127.0.0.0/8

# If you have made changes to this file, you must send a HANGUP signal
# to uHub so that it will re-read the configuration files.
# For example by invoking: 'killall -HUP uhub'
```

And my uhub.conf file

```
# uhub.conf - A example configuration file.
# You should normally place this file in /etc/uhub/uhub.conf
# And change the file_acl and file_motd below.
#
# This file is read only to the uhub deamon, and if you
# make changes to it while uhub is running you can send a
# HUP signal to it, to reparse configuration (only on UNIX). 

# Bind to this port and address
# server_bind_addr=any means listen to "::" if IPv6 is supported
# by the host OS, otherwise 0.0.0.0.
server_port=1511
server_bind_addr=any

# The maximum amount of users allowed on the hub.
max_users=500

# If 1, will show a "This hub is running uhub/version".
show_banner=1

# Allow only registered users on the hub if set to 1.
registered_users_only=0

# A server name and description.
hub_name=uHub
hub_description=Powered by uHub

# Set this to 0, and the hub will disconnect everyone
hub_enabled=1

# Access control list (user database)
file_acl=/etc/uhub/users.conf

# This file can contain a message of the day. A welcome
# message send to any client when connecting.
# If the file does not exist, is empty, or cannot be opened
# the motd will not be sent to the clients.
# Normally this message is sent to clients when connecting.
file_motd=/etc/uhub/motd.txt

# Configure status message as sent to clients in different circumstances.
msg_hub_full                   = Hub is full
msg_hub_disabled               = Hub is disabled
msg_hub_registered_users_only  = Hub is for registered users only
msg_inf_error_nick_missing     = No nickname given
msg_inf_error_nick_multiple    = Multiple nicknames given
msg_inf_error_nick_invalid     = Nickname is invalid
msg_inf_error_nick_long        = Nickname too long
msg_inf_error_nick_short       = Nickname too short
msg_inf_error_nick_spaces      = Nickname cannot start with spaces
msg_inf_error_nick_bad_chars   = Nickname contains invalid characters
msg_inf_error_nick_not_utf8    = Nickname is not valid utf8
msg_inf_error_nick_taken       = Nickname is already in use
msg_inf_error_nick_restricted  = Nickname cannot be used on this hub
msg_inf_error_cid_invalid      = CID is not valid
msg_inf_error_cid_missing      = CID is not specified
msg_inf_error_cid_taken        = CID is taken
msg_inf_error_pid_missing      = PID is not specified
msg_inf_error_pid_invalid      = PID is invalid
msg_ban_permanently            = Banned permanently
msg_ban_temporarily            = Banned temporarily
msg_auth_invalid_password      = Password is wrong
msg_auth_user_not_found        = User not found in password database
msg_error_no_memory            = No memory
```

I tried tinkering with all the settings but still unable to figure out the problem.

Comment: Where do you send the error messages of the server? You should check this on the *server side*, which is much more informative than the *client side*.

Comment: Retag needed - it's nor linux nor networking question, just pure DC++

Comment: @MariusMatutiae the conf are from server side, I did check the server side settings but cant find the solution, uHub uses only the above two conf files and both doesn't have any specific setting for configuring CID.

Comment: Can I try to connect to you uhub from my clients?

Comment: @Lazy Badger Sorry, but our ISP has not assigned us Public IP. Only people in my LAN would be able to access my HUB.

Answer (score 0):

It's a problem of your **DC-client** (ancient???), which uses invalid CID. Check and fix  node in DCPlusPlus.xml (or just remove line - it will be auto-generated at next start, I hope - correctly)

Comment: I edited the DCPlusPlus.xml and removed the CID node, It did auto generate but still the same error. Also the client is latest version

Comment: @Antony - which DC-client used? There are a lot of it. Try another client? Check (show) new CID and fix it by hand? I have rather old uhub and none problem with different dc-clients

Comment: I tried with ApexDC++ and DC++, both show the same error. This is my CID=LMZSX7KSCUUMY77ADGJZ5BBBVQG3UEE7LZTA7GQ. in DCplusplus file. My uhub version 0.2.8-3. Could u share with me your uhub conf files. BTW which client are you using?

Comment: @Antony - I used ApexDC DC++ EiskaltDC++ FlylinkDC++ RSX++ StrongDC. Today's attempt `2015-06-28 06:24:42  INFO: Starting uHub/0.3.0-rc4, listening on 0.0.0.0:15000...
2015-06-28 06:24:42  WARN: Windows system, limited to 4096 connections.
2015-06-28 06:31:09  USER: LoginOK     AAAB/KGUB35MYO4YV6JAPFCGQDQWPJGU67SIKJK6M36Q 10.1.14.94 "Bear" (guest) "StrgDC++ 2.42"
2015-06-28 06:35:48  USER: Logout      AAAB/KGUB35MYO4YV6JAPFCGQDQWPJGU67SIKJK6M36Q 10.1.14.94 "Bear" (disconnected)`